# Retrieve specific items from list Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-item, query

I´m working on Web API to give permissions a public SharePoint online website, so I call list like these

```
 public List<MenuPrincipal> GetMenuOptions(string idioma)
        {
            List<MenuPrincipal> result = new List<MenuPrincipal>();
            try
            {
                SecureString pwd = SPAccess.GetPasswordFromConsoleInput(Definitions.UserPassword);

                using (var context = new ClientContext(Definitions.WebUrl))
                {
                    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Definitions.UserName, pwd);
                    List listResult = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MenuPrincipal");



                    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Idioma'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>", idioma);
                    ListItemCollection items = listResult.GetItems(query);

                    context.Load(items);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (ListItem item in items)
                    {
                        result.Add(new MenuPrincipal
                        {
                            Titile = item["Title"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Title"].ToString(),
                            Enlace = item["Enlace"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Enlace"].ToString(),
                            Posicion = item["Posicion"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item["Posicion"]),
                            Idioma = item["Idioma"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Idioma"].ToString(),
                            Funcion = item["Funcion"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Funcion"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return result.OrderBy(x => x.Posicion).ToList();
        }
```

It works fine, but the speed of my page is very low now. The problem is in my foreach, it calls alot of values, and I only five of these, how can I achieve that call only values I have into my foreach instead all other ones.

There is picture of problem:
[image]
[image]
Help is very appreciated Regards

---

### Update

As I can see query gets a list of 5 arrays, and each one has "56" values, why is it happening?
[image]
[image]
 I read something in MSDN to change my `context.Load`like this:

```
       context.Load(
                items,
                    lists => lists.Include(
                    list => list.Title,
                    list => list.Enlace,
                    list => list.Posicion,
                    list => list.Idioma,
                    list => list.Funcion));
```

But I can´t retrieve value from list so all marked in red like this:

[image]

There is [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538683(v=office.14).aspx) link

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two things here: `ListItem`s and `Field`s.

In one of your screenshots, you can clearly see that the number of list items in your list item collection `items` that is returned form your query is 5.  It says `items` `Count=5`.

That means that the `foreach` is only looping over 5 items.

Where you see the 56 is *in* each item, as field values.  That means each list item you get has 56 field (column) values with it.  But, *you are not looping over 56 field values*, or even touching most of them, you are only working with (coincidentally) 5 fields: `Title`, `Enlace`, `Posicion`, `Idioma` and `Funcion`.

So your slow page performance is not due to looping over many items.  It must be because of something else.

> As I can see query gets a list of 5 arrays, and each one have "56"
>   values, why it happening?

Right, so your query returns 5 items.  If there are 56 field values, it means that the list you are getting the items from has many, many columns on it.  *Some* of those field values are probably hidden fields for internal SharePoint use, so we can't say that your list has 56 columns.  But it probably has a lot of columns, and you are not telling SharePoint which specific fields/columns you want on each item, so it's just sending them all back to you.

Now, if you want to retrieve the list items, and *not* bring back all 56 field values, but *only* bring back the 5 field values you want to work with, you need to use [`ViewFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields(v=office.14).aspx) in your query to specify exactly which field values you want returned, like this:

```
string queryString = "<View>";
queryString += string.Format("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Idioma'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>", idioma);
queryString += "<ViewFields>";
queryString += "<FieldRef Name='Title' />";
queryString += "<FieldRef Name='Enlace' />";
queryString += "<FieldRef Name='Posicison' />";
queryString += "<FieldRef Name='Idioma' />";
queryString += "<FieldRef Name='Funcion' />";
queryString += "</ViewFields></View>";

CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = queryString;
ListItemCollection items = listResult.GetItems(query);
```

This might help a little bit because it means much less data is being transferred from the server when you make your query.